# Doctrine ORM unable to persist one side of ManyToMany (SQLSTATE[23000]: UNIQUE constraint violation)

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm new(ish) to Symfony 4 and Doctrine so perhaps I'm expecting too much from the Doctrine ORM but the fact I can't find suitable documentation to inform me either way is driving me nuts!

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: skill.id
```

**Summary**
I've created a ManyToMany relationship between my Player and Skill Entities. Each of these entities has its ID set manually because they are coming from an external API. I am building up the data in the PlayerController which scrapes the 3rd party API to cache the data locally in my DB.

The code I've written allows the storing (caching) of the 3rd party data in my database if the skill i'm adding hasn't already been added to the database. However, if I try to add another player that shares that skill the entire transaction fails because it can't add the skill again due to the unique id constraint.  I totally get this but I thought Doctrine ORM was clever enough to simply create the entry in the junction table and ignore the already existing skill.

Am I expecting too much of Doctrine and if so are there any services or helpers to get me out of this situation without writing a bunch of code.

The PlayerController performs this action to persist the data:

```
private function persistPlayer($data){

    $player = new Player($data);  //Player __construct entity extracts + assigns data

    foreach ($data->skills as $rawSkill) {
                $skill = new Skill($rawSkill);
                $player->addSkill($skill);
            }
    }

    $this->entityManager->persist($player);

    try {

        $this->entityManager->flush();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        error_log($e->getMessage());

    }
    return $player;
}
```

My Entities annotations look like this (and were created using the `bin/console make:entity`  command:

```
class Player
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", inversedBy="skill",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $skill;




public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->ability = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->setId($data->id);
}


   public function addSkill(Skill $skill): self
    {
        if (!$this->skill->contains($skill)) {
            $this->skill[] = $skill;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    //.... more code

}
```

And my Skill Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SkillRepository")
 */
class Skill
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Player", mappedBy="skill" ,cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $skill;


    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->ability = new ArrayCollection();

         $this->setId($data->id);

    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        return $this->id = $id;
    }


//...more code


}
```

My junction table is created using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE player_skill (player_id INTEGER NOT NULL, skill_id 
INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(player_id, skill_id))
```

Comment: Can you add the Player and Skill constructors code also?

Comment: They both contain array colletions

Comment: Do you set the skill id there? Could you add the relevant code, maybe it would help?

Comment: I've added the two constructors.

Comment: the column names in the link table should be, player_id, skill_id

Comment: i share new table structure with new answer, can you try table structure?

Answer (score -1):

Try below annotation:

```
class Player
{

...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", inversedBy="skill",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="player_skill")
 *
 */
private $skill;

...

}
```

like this, with relation table name

Comment: Tried it and it made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: can you share the intermediate table structure you are using?

Comment: I'll add it to the original question (sorry for the delay)

Answer (score -2):

can you try the following table structure?

```
CREATE TABLE `player_skill` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `playerSkill_skillId_idx` (`skill_id`), KEY `playerSkill_playerId_idx` (`player_id`), CONSTRAINT `playerSkill_skillId_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`skill_id`) REFERENCES `skill` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT `playerSkill_playerId_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `player` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and follow annotation with

```
class Player
{

...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", 
inversedBy="skill",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="player_skill")
 *
 */
private $skill;

...

}
```